# Binary subtree detection - Why to compare 2 traversals

Tags: algorithm, tree, binary-tree

1. Why do we need to compare in-order traversal string AND pre-order traversal string to determine if a tree is a subtree of a bigger tree? Why is 1 traversal string not enough?
2. Can we replace one of the above strings with the post-order traversal string?

Assume:

1. I have an unbalanced binary tree. This is NOT necessarily a binary search tree.
2. Data at inner nodes and leaves can be compared using a given compareTO() method
3. The tree is huge, thus making use of suffix trees impossible. Assume normal recursion is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Ad1.** Let's say you have your bigger tree:

```
     5
   /
  6     <something>
 / \
7   3
   /       
  2
```

Now notice that the inorder traversal of the subtree rooted at node `6` will be `[7,6,2,3]`. Now tell me what will be the inorder traversal of the following tree:

```
  6
 / \
7   2
     \      
      3
```

You guessed it: `[7,6,2,3]`. Inorder traversal does not, **in general case** describe a single binary tree but a number of binary trees. Should this be a **binary search tree** then you only need 1 preorder *or* postorder traversal since the inorder traversal will always be the same (all nodes in a sorted order).

**Ad2.** You can reconstruct a tree with inorder and preorder *or* postorder traversals. You cannot, in the general case, reconstruct a tree with a preorder and postorder traversals, there might be more than 1 option. The only case where you can do that is for a full binary tree (each node, except the leaves, has to have 2 children).